# How Does comment_author Filter Work?

Tags: filters, comments, author

I want my plugin to add extra text after a comment author's name. For example if they've commented as "Albert", I might want the comments section to display their name as "Albert (genius)".

I'm trying to use the [comment_author filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_author/) as follows, but it doesn't seem to have any visible effect:

```
function my_author_filter($author) {

    return $author . '( genius)';

}

add_filter( 'comment_author', 'my_author_filter');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes themes call `get_comment_author` instead, and bypass the comment_author function. Try using that filter instead.